# Erro no Codigo PHP Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

Tags: php, mysqli

O erro do meu codigo está na Conexão com a base de Dados, é o seguinte:

> mysqli_select_db() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given

```
<?php
   $servidor='localhost';
   $banco='isartes';
   $usuario='root';
   $senha='';
   $conexao=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);
   if(!($conexao)){
      echo "Conexao Falhada"; exit;
   }
   $selecao = mysqli_select_db($conexao);
   if(!($selecao)){
      echo "Base de dados nao achada";
      exit;
   }
?>
```

Comment: Faltou passar a conexão para a função. Minha sugestão é não usar ela, e passar o nome do banco como quarto argumento do `mysqli_connect()`

Comment: O trexo do Codigo está logo a seguir! <?php
 
 $servidor='localhost';
 $banco='isartes';
 $usuario='root';
 $senha='';
 $conexao=mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha); 
 if(!($conexao)){
  echo "Conexao Falhada";
  exit;
 }
 $selecao= mysqli_select_db($conexao);
 if(!($selecao)){
  echo "Base de dados nao achada";
  exit;
 }

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A maioria das funções do MySQLi pedem a conexão como primeiro argumento. O erro indica que dois argumentos deveriam ser passados, porém apenas um foi passado.

Existe duas formas de resolver o problema a primeira é fazer o que diz o erro, passar o nome do banco depois da conexão.

A segunda é não utilizar essa função e passar o nome do banco de dados como quarto argumento da função `mysqli_connect()`.

Primeira forma:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha);
mysqli_select_db($conexao, $banco);
```

Segunda forma:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect($servidor,$usuario,$senha, $banco);
```

Comment: Valeu muito Irmao!!

Comment: @SetimoMutecaJr. você pode marcar a resposta com o sinal verde, isso significa que uma resposta resolveu o problema. Pode dar uma olhada em: [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/91)